# Ginkgo skipped specs counted as failed

Tags: go, bdd, ginkgo

I've being using Ginkgo for a while and I have found a behavior I don't really understand. I have a set of specs that I only want to run if and only if a condition is available. If the condition is not available I want to skip the test suite.

Something like this:

```
   ginkgo.BeforeSuite(func(){
    if !CheckCondition() {
        ginkgo.Skip("condition not available")
    } 
   }
```

When the suite is skipped this counts as a failure.

```
FAIL! -- 0 Passed | 1 Failed | 0 Pending | 0 Skipped
```

I assumed there should be one tests to be considered to be skipped. Am I missing something? Any comments are welcome.

Thnaks

Comment: "0 Skipped" means you're not skipping anything.

Comment: From the documentation, it appears that Skip() works at spec level and not at test suite level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `Skip` method incorrectly. It should be use inside spec like below, not inside `BeforeSuite`. When used inside spec it does show up as "skipped" in the summary.

```
It("should do something, if it can", func() {
    if !someCondition {
        Skip("special condition wasn't met")
    }
})
```

https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#the-spec-runner

Comment: OK I see. I'm surprised there is not a direct way to simply skip a test suite from the BeforeSuite.